# Odd & Sporadic Chrome Error: The chunked cookie is incomplete

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-chrome, cookies

We have a .NET Framework 4.7 Azure hosted web app that has been running smoothly now for a long time. We've told all of our users that they should be using Chrome, and as far as we know, most do.

A few weeks ago, a user reported an odd server-side error. The on-screen message wasn't very helpful, so we turned off Custom Errors. That seemed to help us get the actual error message:

> The chunked cookie is incomplete. Only 0 of the expected chunks were found, totaling 0 characters. A client size limit may have been exceeded.

We had never seen that error before, but a quick search offered a solution. We asked the user to clear cookies and try again. That worked. Then a few days later, two more users reported the exact same error.  Then more. And then more. The initial fix worked for some, but not others. Eventually, we came up with the following steps:

---

1. Log out of all of our applications. Close all Chrome tabs and windows. Open a new Chrome window.
2. Clear browser data
   a. Click on the three dots in the upper right corner
   b. Select “More Tools > Clear Browser Data”
   c. Probably best to select “All Time” but the user may try a shorter time frame at first
3. Reset Chrome to default settings
   a. Instructions:  https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en
4. Close all Chrome tabs and windows and try again.

***IF*** it still does not work, then follow these steps…

1. Log out of all of our applications. Close all Chrome tabs and windows. Open a new Chrome window.
2. In the URL bar, copy and paste this address: chrome://flags
3. In the search bar, type: samesite
4. Your window should now look like this:
   [image]
5. For all three options, change the dropdown from Default to Enabled
6. Click the “RELAUNCH” button in the lower right.
7. After Chrome re-launches, go back to the app as you normally would.
   a. You *should* now have access.
   b. However, we’re not done yet!
8. Repeat 1-5 above, and this time reset all three options back to Default.
   a. Then again click the “RELAUNCH” button.

***IF*** it still does not work, then follow these steps…

1. Try to access our application via Microsoft Edge

---

(We stopped asking users to try in an incognito window because so many of their offices restrict its usage.)

In the meantime, we are working like mad to try and identify the actual cause of the error. Surprisingly, there isn't much chatter about this one. It seems to be related to a recent update in how Chrome handles same-site cookies, but the main issue is... we can't reproduce it. It seems to be popping up at random. And some users report the error going away w/o them doing anything.

And, then, of course... we have one single user for whom NONE of the steps above work. Not even using Edge. So far, the steps above have worked for everyone BUT him.

Has ANYONE run into something like this before? Any ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Hi Casey, I have the same problem with some users, but I didn't reproduce it. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your post, Casey. I'm now dealing with the same problem on my web app . Have you by any chance reached a conclusion regarding the actual cause of the error?

Comment: @Daniel, I just posted an answer. We struggled with this for a LONG time before we finally got it solved. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any who may run into this error, here's how we eventually solved it. At this point, I am going off long-term memory so I will try and be as accurate as possible.

The problem was due to putting too much data into a cookie. In our case, the cookie was being used as a validation token.

The reason the error just started happening seemingly at random was that some browsers (ie: chrome) included a cookie length limit in an update. So when a user's browser version was updated, they would start seeing the error.

We had to first figure out which cookie was causing the error. That wasn't hard because most had very short values. Once we knew which cookie was the issue, we then just figured out how to substantially reduce the amount of data being written to it.

Comment: Thank you @Casey. I am tying to reduce the size as well.
But what I don't really understand is that, in my case, the problem appears for a certain portion of my clients ( from a specific area ) - and what I find odd is that it also shows in the incognito tab
Have you, by any chance, had tried this in incognito before?

Comment: You are correct that the error is extremely sporadic. Yes, we (meaning we, the developers) tested in incognito. But the problem was... we could never reproduce the error on our side, and most of the end-users who were seeing the error had corporate policies in place that prevented them from using incognito. This made it very hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: The irony here is that the cookie chunking manager is designed to specifically deal with the problem of too large cookies, by breaking them into chunks.

A case where I've seen this error occur is when some layer out side of the web application increases the cookie size -- this breaks the assumptions of the cookie chunker, resulting in too large cookies. You can work around this by reducing the max chunk size.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've got a website that's been driving me crazy for months -- wouldn't keep me signed in, and I kept getting the "chunked cookie" error when I came in through e-mail bulletins. Based on the answer, I just went into the Chrome settings and blew away the cookies for the problem site, and everything suddenly worked fine. Hopefully it continues to work.